# Why sendKeys() in Windows IE 11 no longer persists after upgrading to Selenium Java 3.14.0?

Tags: java, selenium, internet-explorer-11

The code for creating an InternetExplorerDriver:

```
InternetExplorerOptions options = new InternetExplorerOptions();
options.setCapability("nativeEvents", false);
WebDriver ieDriver = new InternetExplorerDriver(options);
```

`sendKeys()` was working completely fine until [Selenium](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java) 3.13.0.
However, after I upgraded to 3.14.0 above, `sendKeys()` will type characters into an `input` field but all that has been typed will disappear when the focus moves away from that input element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [Change Log](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/CHANGELOG), there was a brief mention about `ieOptions`:

```
* Add native events under se:ieOptions. (#6183)
```

The content of this change can be found [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/pulls?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Apr%206183).

If you are using `options.setCapability("nativeEvents", false);` in your code and then upgrade to Selenium 3.14.0 above you might experience similar case where anything typed on an `input` HTML element using `sendKeys()` will no longer persist.

Changing the code to `options.setCapability("NATIVE_EVENTS", false);` did the trick for me.